# Interpretation "set defined by equations"

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

In Strichartz's "The way of Analysis" exercise two of part 4.1.5 it is asked to show that a certain set $A$ is closed and/or compact. My question is not about how to proof that fact. My question is about how to translate, step by step, the sentence that describes how this set is constructed. It says: "Let A be the set defined by the equations $f_1(x) = 0$, $f_2(x) = 0$, . . . , $f_n(x) = 0$, where $f_1, ... , f_n$ are continuous functions defined
on the whole line."

Is A just {0}? Is it {0,0,...,0} (n zeros, one for each equation) which reduces to {0}? Is it the x values that 'solve' each equation? How would the set A change if there was just one equation defining it instead of a system? Please help me understand what the set A actually looks like.

Comment: Take an example, say $X=\{x,y\}$ and $f_1(x,y)=x^2+y$ and $f_2(x,y)=x+y^2$. Then solve $f_1=f_2=0$. The set of solutions is $A$. Is $A$ just $\{0\}$? Or for the real line, take $f_1(x)=2x^2-x$ and $f_2(x)=2x-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $A$ is defined as
$$
A = \{x \in \mathbb R \mid f_1(x) = 0 \text{ and } f_2(x) = 0 \text{ and } \cdots f_n(x) = 0\}.
$$
If it was just a single equation $f(x) = 0$, then you would have $A = \{x \in \mathbb R \mid f(x) = 0\}$, i.e., the set of $x$ for which that equation is true.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it is the the x values that 'solve' each equation. It is the intersection of solutions to each equation of the system.